# How does one create an SPL token with a name, symbol, and metadata?

Tags: metadata

I am trying to create a fungible SPL token with a name and symbol that shows on Solscan. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage the new Token Extensions to do this, specifically the metadata extension.

You can read the [written guide](https://solana.com/developers/guides/token-extensions/metadata-pointer) or check the [tutorial on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7EyQUlNAdw) and there is an example on the [Solana Playground](https://beta.solpg.io/65964e90cffcf4b13384ceca).